# What is the purpose of textContent in an input element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Provided an input element in a DOM, it does have a `textContent` property along with `value`.  It is well known that the value of the input is what shown in the text box, and this element cannot have any children, that is `<input>something</input>` still gives an empty input followed by a sibling text node, whereas closing tag is completely ignored.  But when we set a value to the `textContent` of this input, it is somehow survives the round-trip:

```
input.textContent = 'something'
console.log(input.textContent)  // this works
```

Also, after setting the property, the input appear as having child elements in the inspector:
[image: Safari inspector screenshot after setting the text content]

Maybe it's just me, but I fail to see any logical consistency here.  Wouldn't it be nice to have a Type Error on setting text content to the input?

Is there any reasoning behind present behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM is not HTML, but an API for tree structures that comply with the [XML information set](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/) Translating `<input>something</input>` into an input element followed by a text node is the behaviour of the HTML parser, not the behaviour of the DOM.

In fact, if you use XHTML, served as `application/xhtml+xml`, `<input>something</input>` will become an input element with a text node child, the same as using `.textContent`. So it's entirely normal that `.textContent` works the way it does.