# Replace text content of Current Target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 sliders on my website and would like to change the values of the slide and replace it with text.

```js
$('.slider').on('input', (event) => {
  if ($(event.currentTarget).val() === '0') {
    $(event.currentTarget).text('test');

  } else if (event.currentTarget.value === '1') {
    console.log('display')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer mx-4 text-center pb-4 w-50 mx-auto">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" value="0" class="slider" id="range-bureautique">to be replaced
  <div class="display linest" id="score-bureautique"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

With console.log() I can see that the value is getting equat to 0 or to 1 when i move the slider but the html content is not replaced with my 'test' text ...

Thanks!

Comment: An `<input>`-element really is only good for input. If you want to display text related to the input, you should use a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)-element. (You should read up on it, it's quite useful!)

Comment: You can change the text of an input, it just doesn't do anything in HTML. See [What is the purpose of textContent in an input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37143171/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `$(event.currentTarget).text('test')` will update the text-content of the input-tag. But there is no such thing! Note that there is no end-tag to the input-tag. You should use some tag with id set ideally. Something like this:

```
<input ...><label id="my_label">to be replaced</label>
```

Then you use any of this jQuery thing to update the text:

```
$("#my_label").text('test');
$("#my_label").text($(event.currentTarget).val());
```

So with an update to the snippet:

```js
$('.slider').on('input', (event) => {
    $("#my_label").text($(event.currentTarget).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer mx-4 text-center pb-4 w-50 mx-auto">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" value="0" class="slider" id="range-bureautique">
      <label id="my_label">to be replaced</label>
  <div class="display linest" id="score-bureautique"></div>
</div>
</div>
```